# MCV3 get ScreenSize

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to create a URL for a link on my webpage based on end user's available screen size like rdp://myworkdesktop.comp.com?resolution=1600x900

I get the computer name from user profile in AD so it will different for every user and is dynamically generated by the backend. Is there any way I can form a url like that in MVC3 view with half of the info coming from server and another half on the client side?

I am new to web programming.
Any pointers or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `window.screen.width` and `window.screen.height`, though I'm not sure about compatibility.

Comment: I am trying that but couldn't figure out how to append to a value coming from the server

Comment: @Bhuvan: Well, you'd have to store it beforehand. The server can't know without the client.